# How to unit test structured logging calls using NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have a method which has a line as follows:

```
_logger.LogError(exception, $"Encountered {exception.GetType().Name}. Unable to verify user with id {user.UserId}");
```

This has a corresponding unit test with the following assertion:

```
var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<SyncService>>();

// other Arrange, Act, Assert steps

logger.Received(1).LogError(exception, "Encountered NullReferenceException. Unable to verify user with id 1");
```

This test was running fine.

However, due to some issues we encountered, this log now needs to be converted into a structured log.

So now the line in the class looks as follows:

```
_logger.LogError(exception, "Encountered {exceptionType}. Unable to verify user with id {userId}", exception.GetType().Name, user.UserId);
```

But now when I changed the assertion to the following the test fails:

```
logger.Received(1).LogError(exception, "Encountered {exceptionType}. Unable to verify user with id {userId}", "NullReferenceException", 1);
```

The error message is as follows. I have removed the unwanted stack traces to highlight only the important parts:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive exactly 1 call matching:
    Log<FormattedLogValues>(Error, 0, Encountered NullReferenceException. Unable to verify user with id 1, System.NullReferenceException: Test Exception
   at NSubstitute.ExceptionExtensions.ExceptionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Throws>b__0(CallInfo _)

   ...// complete stack trace ...

Actually received no matching calls.

Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
    Log<FormattedLogValues>(Error, 0, *Encountered NullReferenceException. Unable to verify user with id 1*, System.NullReferenceException: Test Exception
   at NSubstitute.ExceptionExtensions.ExceptionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Throws>b__0(CallInfo _)
```

I was initially unable to figure out what I am doing incorrectly. From the 2 messages it seems like the correct method is being called with the correct parameters, but the message is still flagged as non-matching.

But after some digging I came to realize the flagged message is actually a `ToString()` call to `FormattedLogValues` which happens when the exception is thrown. Internally, it is trying to compare an instance of `string` to an instance of `FormattedLogValues`

I tried to directly assert on `Log<FormattedLogValues>` but it seems like the class `FormattedLogValues` is not available for external use.

This is how the issue was resolved earlier: https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/384

But now the struct `FormattedLogValues` is no longer available for public use. There is an open issue regarding this here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67577

But now the question is, how do I test this? I know Moq has a method called `It.IsAnyType()` which can be used to ignore the type of the message template, but does NSubstitute have anything similar?

I have seen some other posts in StackOverflow with similar issues but the answers do not seem to work when structured logs are used

Comment: Scroll [this](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/) down to : "Received (or not) with specific arguments" ... and related: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/

Comment: Another rather unrelated question would be: Do you _really need to_ unit test your _logging_?

Comment: Not for all methods, but this method does not return any data for me to assert on. On success, it publishes a message to AmazonSQS and on failure, it logs the exception. The success is asserted by verifying the call to AmazonSQS and the failure is asserted by making sure the message is correctly logged.

The failure itself is transient so we only monitor the logs if an issue arises, but its important to add structured logging because we want to be able to filter the logs by the userId.

Comment: `calculator.DidNotReceive().Add(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Is<int>(x => x >= 500));`

This line itself is the problem. I am unable to use `Arg.Is<FormattedLogValues>()` because the type FormattedLogValues itself is not accessible outside the package.

I was thinking of something like `Arg.IsAnyType()` for only a specific argument rather than `ReceivedWithAnyArgs()`, which ignores all the arguments.

Comment: Upvoted to attract someone with better knowledge of NSubstitute. Atm, I cannot fire something up quickly to just try it out.

Comment: @Fildor to your question regarding whether logging should be tested, my answer tends to be "yes", because logging is an externally observable, intentional behavior. I usually treat it as a first-class behavior in my systems, to the point that, in a few cases, I might have classes that are 100% dedicated to _only_ logging and doing nothing else (usually using the decorator pattern). This is, of course, fairly subjective. Many people will say that logging is secondary and shouldn't be tested. Just figured I'd share with you here why I disagree with that notion.

Comment: _" to your question regarding whether logging should be tested"_ - that's not exactly what I was asking. OP has a valid case to wanting to do so, I think. A general dicussion about the topic is on a different page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one thing you can do, which is something I've myself used in a few occasions.

First, create what we are going to call a "testable" logger abstraction:

```
public abstract class TestableLogger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    public abstract IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        where TState : notnull;

    public abstract bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel);

    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception? exception,
        Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        this.Log(logLevel, eventId, state?.ToString(), exception);
    }

    public abstract void Log(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        string? state,
        Exception? exception);
}
```

The purpose of this wrapper is to implement `ILogger<T>` as faithfully as possible, while allowing you to make assertions on a slight variation of the original `Log<TState>` method: we are "simplifying" the implementation by bypassing the internal formatter/TState class by just calling `ToString` on the  `TState` argument.

We don't really care about the `BeginScope` and `IsEnabled` original members, so we just "pass those over" by implementing them abstractly.

Then, you can now substitute over this new abstract class instead of the original `ILogger<T>` and assert on it, like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var user = new User { UserId = 1 };
        var exception = new NullReferenceException();
        var logger = Substitute.For<TestableLogger<Service>>();
        var verifier = Substitute.For<IUserVerifier>();
        verifier
            .When(v => v.Verify(user))
            .Throw(exception);

        var service = new Service(logger, verifier);

        // Act
        service.DoStuff(user);

        // Assert
        logger.Received(1).Log(
            LogLevel.Error,
            Arg.Any<EventId>(),
            "Encountered NullReferenceException. Unable to verify user with id 1",
            exception);
    }
}
```

I've made some assumptions about the rest of your scenario there but this seems sensible. Note I'm asserting using your original message there.

Here is the rest of the code I created to support this example:

```
public interface IUserVerifier
{
    void Verify(User user);
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly ILogger<Service> logger;
    private readonly IUserVerifier userVerifier;

    public Service(ILogger<Service> logger, IUserVerifier userVerifier)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.userVerifier = userVerifier;
    }

    public void DoStuff(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            this.userVerifier.Verify(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(
                ex, 
                "Encountered {exceptionType}. Unable to verify user with id {userId}",
                ex.GetType().Name,
                user.UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

The only caveat here is that you won't be able to assert the individual values passed as structured logging parameters individually, but it is still a somewhat valid assertion IMHO.

An interesting aspect of this approach is that you can actually customize that new abstract method to your liking. I removed just the parts that tend to be problematic, but you could completely change the shape of that method and still be able to assert on top of it, as long as you perform the same call redirection from the original `Log` method.

I'm currently not aware of a different approach that would allow you to specifically test each parameter.

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer as this seems to be a valid work around till the attached discussions about the visibility of `FormattedLogValues` reaches a conclusion.